# Media file Reading

Tags: android, media

i m trying to read thumbnails for the images in my phone. the below code works fine in Emulator but same fails in Phone. It gives `count = 0` (i have many photos in phone):

```
String[] img = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };
cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, img,   null,null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + "");
int image_column_index =  imagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
count = imagecursor.getCount();
System.err.println("image_column_index= " + image_column_index);
System.err.println("count= " + count);
```

hi, thanks for the info.. please find the log below...actually the count shouldn't be zero at all here.

```
    06-16 15:17:28.360 W/System.err(10250): image_column_index= 0
    06-16 15:17:28.360 W/System.err(10250): count= 0
    06-16 15:17:28.370 W/dalvikvm(10250): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020ac0)
    06-16 15:17:28.370 E/AndroidRuntime(10250): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-16 15:17:28.370 E/AndroidRuntime(10250): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.imagegallery/com.test.imagegallery.LocalThumbnailActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    06-16 15:17:28.370 E/AndroidRuntime(10250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
    06-16 15:17:28.370 E/AndroidRuntime(10250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    06-16 15:17:28.370 E/AndroidRuntime(10250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    06-16 15:17:28.370 E/AndroidRuntime(10250):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    06-16 15:17:28.370 E/AndroidRuntime(10250):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    06-16 15:17:28.370 E/AndroidRuntime(10250):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    06-16 15:17:28.370 E/AndroidRuntime(10250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    06-16 15:17:28.370 E/AndroidRuntime(10250):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-16 15:17:28.370 E/AndroidRuntime(10250):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    06-16 15:17:28.370 E/AndroidRuntime(10250):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    06-16 15:17:28.370 E/AndroidRuntime(10250):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    06-16 15:17:28.370 E/AndroidRuntime(10250):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-16 15:17:28.370 E/AndroidRuntime(10250): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    06-16 15:17:28.370 E/AndroidRuntime(10250):     at com.test.imagegallery.LocalThumbnailActivity.init_phone_image_grid(LocalThumbnailActivity.java:48)
    06-16 15:17:28.370 E/AndroidRuntime(10250):     at com.test.imagegallery.LocalThumbnailActivity.onCreate(LocalThumbnailActivity.java:29)
    06-16 15:17:28.370 E/AndroidRuntime(10250):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    06-16 15:17:28.370 E/AndroidRuntime(10250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    06-16 15:17:28.370 E/AndroidRuntime(10250):     ... 11 more
    06-16 15:17:28.380 W/ActivityManager( 1366):   Force finishing activity com.test.imagegallery/.LocalThumbnailActivity
    06-16 15:17:28.380 W/ActivityManager( 1366):   Force finishing activity com.test.imagegallery/.ImageGallery
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(...);
```

The class you mean to instantiate here is called `Cursor` (it's upper case).

Also, you should provide the LogCat output and any Exception or Error-messages you get.

Comment: hi luckas, Cursor was a typo mistake while writing the question here. about log cat i m seeing the error in phone so i cant copy the error here. its shows the count =0 and then ArrayOutOfBoundArray for the activity

Comment: So you're not testing on a virtual device? If so, you should read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html).

Comment: hi, thanks for the info.. please find the log below...actually the count shouldn't be zero at all here.                                count= 0
W/dalvikvm( 5413): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020ac0)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5413): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 5413): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ibm.imagegallery/com.ibm.imagegallery.LocalThumbnailActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
E/AndroidRuntime( 5413):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.jav.. can't show ful log

Comment: Please edit your original post and add the LogCat in code-tags.